# "django-admin.py makemessages -l en" adds Plural-Forms to the output file

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

Every time I run `django-admin.py makemessages -l en`, it adds the following line to the **djangojs.po** file:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

After that, running `python manage.py runserver` breaks with this error:

```
ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous
```

Of course, removing that line will fix the error.
How can I prevent this line from being added?

P.S.
I'm looking for a way to force django-admin not adding this line, or adding something I prefer, or at least something that doesn't produce an error.

I'm using Django 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that was due to missing plural forms in en translation catalogs. As a result django was inserting `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"` as a default (which isn't valid syntax).

It was fixed when django 2.0 was released. See [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28085) for details.

For anyone having problems with this, it may be worth checking your version of django, and updating if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the line with **`"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural= (n != 1);\n"`** in all the occurences of .po files shdould get you going!

gettext usually translates word to word when you use Django translations (i18n & l10n). But it gets trickier when you want to translate (mostly) nouns, into its singular/plural form.
For instance, consider this example:

```
if n == 1:
  string = "%d file is deleted"%n
else:
  string = "%d files are deleted"%n
```

To handle the translation of plurals in internationalization, [Plural-forms](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) is the standard to follow.  Python-Django implements ngettext in the following manner: 
 ([visit doc for your Django version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#pluralization))

```
ngettext('%d file is deleted', '%d files are deleted', n) % n
```

In most of the languages, n!=1 is considered plural. In the above example, when `n=1` Django has to consider `'%d file is deleted'` and `'%d files are deleted'` when `n!=1` for translations. Hence the denifition for plural-forms in .po files goes like this: `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural= (n != 1);\n"`

Now, when you run `makemessages`, Django is trying to help you by adding `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"` line in the .po files, hinting this line has to be replaced with our definition of plural-forms.

Note: 
Not every language would have 2 plurals, for instance, Japanese, Vietnamese, Korean, Thai doesn't need to differentiate between singular and plural (hence `Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;`). On the other hand, there are some languages like Romanian, Lithuanian, Russian, Polish where `nplurals=3`. Check out [this link](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) for further examples.

Hopefully in your case, nplurals=1. If not visit [this link](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html) for plurals-form.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much but it wasn't my answer, please read my question again. I did know all of your explanation, but I'm looking for a way to force django-admin removing this line of hint or adding something I prefer or at least something don't produce an error.

Comment: Oh Okay, my bad! But you do have ngettext function calls in your code, is it?

Comment: Yes, I have some